# Import Local json data into React State

Tags: json, reactjs

I'm making an app that is meant to give me practice using routes, so this is initially using static, local test data. It's in json format already, and it's an object consisting of two arrays (folders and notes). I just want my initial state to be this data. Here's what I tried already:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom';
... other imports ...
import store from './dummy-store.js';


class App extends Component {
  state = {
    folder: [],
    notes: []
  };

  componentDidMount () {
    fetch(store)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(folder notes => this.setState({ folder notes })) 
  }

  render() {
....code...
}
}
```

Comment: If it's an imported JSON object you *can* just use it. No need to fetch it, it's already imported.

Comment: @DrewReese
state = {
  actual jason data...?
}

Comment: I think there should be a comma between folder and notes in line .then(folder notes => this.setState({ folder notes })) . check it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If, for example, your JSON file was

```
{
  "folders": [ ... ],
  "notes": [ ... ],
  ...
}
```

If imported as a local asset ***within*** (i.e. bundled with) your app code, access in code

```
import store from './dummy-store.js';

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    folder: store.folder,
    notes: store.notes,
  };
...
```

If fetched as a public asset ***external*** (i.e. in the public folder, somewhere out on the web, etc..) to your app

```
class App extends Component {
  state = {
    folder: [],
    notes: []
  };

  componentDidMount () {
    fetch("pathToJsonFile")
      // return JSON object
      .then(res => res.json())
      // uses object destructuring of passed parameter
      .then(({folder, notes}) => this.setState({ folder, notes })) 
  }
...
```

[image: Edit strange-nash-uxj6o]

Answer (score 1):

You dont need to fetch because you already imported it, you can pass it as initial state to `useState`

```
const [state, setState] = useState(store);
```

you can check here https://codesandbox.io/s/silly-golick-rshco